# Two fluid divs nex to one with fixed size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with placing two fluid divs next to one with  fixed size.
This picture will better explain what I'm trying to do[image]

`#menu` is with fixed width;

`#owl` is 60% of the wrapper;

`#right` menu is 40% of the wrapper

Bigger version of the picture http://prntscr.com/5071zd
Thank in advance.

Comment: Try flexboxes http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tek5t11f/

Comment: @Anon the #wrapper must not be with  fixed width - the max width is 1024 and if the window is less than 1024px the wrapper also must shrink

Comment: Please tell us what exactly is your problem ? To what point did you achieve the work and what part is missing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jnmLu69z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this solution.
I have warped the right part to a new div to set the width 100%.
The only problem is that second margin has to be added as percentage if you want to avoid `calc()`.

```css
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    border: 4px solid black;
}
#inner_container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 110px;
}
#owl {
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    border: 4px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
#right_menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 38%;
    border: 4px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2%
}
#menu, #inner_container, #owl, #right_menu {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">menu</div>
    <div id="inner_container">
        <div id="owl">owl</div><!--
     --><div id="right_menu">right menu</div>
    <div>   
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxk7j07k/

Comment: Thank you for your solusion, I've upvoted your answer and after trying it on "the field" and if its working will click on accept.

Comment: Sure, please tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

the #owl width: 60% will take 60% of the parent div #wrapper.

. #owl width + #right-menu + #menu = 100px + 60% + 40% .

Is better ifcan you wrap your #owl and #right-menu together is one div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="#menu></div> // 100px
    <div class="inner-warpper> // this will take the rest of the #wrapper width
        <div id="owl"></div> width 60% of the #inner-wrapper
        <div id="right-menu"></div> width 40% of the #inner-wrapper
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j2arkx66/

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the markup a little.

HTML is reduced to:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="owl"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Note: I have created this example without a container, but a container could be used if really needed.

### The CSS

- `max-width: 1024px` is placed on the body which will be centered with `margin: 0 auto`
- `vertical-align: top` to go along with `display: inline-block` is going to come in handy when you add text. This prevents the columns from being dragged down as the [default vertical-align value is `baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Values_(for_inline_elements))
- The left and right flexible columns are given `width: calc(x% - 60px)` to account for the 10px gaps and the left menu between them. Older browsers ([IE 8 and below](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)) are accounted for with an un-optimised width. This is a great opportunity for graceful degradation in older browsers.
- The `min-height: 100%`on the columns allow them to stretch with content. The 100% height is received through the `height: 100%` on `html,body`

### Working Example

Note the use of `<!-- -->`. This is to remove a [gap that occurs when using inline elements.](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu {
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#owl {
  width: 50.5%;
  width: calc(60% - 60px);
  border: 4px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#right {
  width: 30.5%;
  width: calc(40% - 60px);
  border: 4px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">menu</div><!--
--><div id="owl">owl</div><!--
--><div id="right">right</div>
```